# Sharing content with "better" websites in exchange for links back to my site

Tags: seo, blog

I run a blog like site with programming related content. I have been approached with a proposal to cross post my content on another site. The other site would add a link back to the original page on my site.

The other site seems fancier and probably has a better ranking than mine.

Now I'm wondering which one of the two statements below is most likely:

- Since the other site is fancier (and probably have better overall pagerank) it will show up above my site in search results and "steal" my visitors.

  It will have a **net negative** impact on my visitor count.

or

- Search engines understands that I have the original source and getting linked to from a highly ranked site outweighs any other downsides.

  It will have a **net positive** impact on my visitor count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a fan of duplicating content on other sites. It can be done, but why give away your own work? That is how I feel about things.

Be that as it may, if you chose to, you must get assurances that the other site will place a canonical tag in their copy of the page pointing to your original content. Do not share your content without this.

Also, make sure they attribute your work with an author profile and actual link to your content/site. Make sure this link does not have *nofollow* in it. Do not share your content without this.

Get your agreement in writing. Do not skip this step. Type up a basic agreement, a letter of understanding, with all the criteria you expect them to provide.

Otherwise, without these things, there is no up-side for you.

On the positive side, having content with a canonical tag to your content, attribution, and a link to your site can boost your sites importance in the search engines. However, like you said, the nature of things may change.

What you may lose in search to this site could positively effect your site in other ways. For example, people following the links to your site to see what else they can find.

Also do not share all of your content. Just some of it. Save something for yourself. How much you decide. Perhaps keep half or two thirds depending upon how much you have. If you do this, your site may see an increase in search results to the content you chose to keep. Who knows for sure?

Lastly, think about what specifically you are willing to share. Do you have unique content that exists no where else? Perhaps you will want to keep this content and share simpler more common content that you do not compete well for anyway.

Before making the decision, research this other site thoroughly. Get as much information about ranking, do not use Alexa, but do check other performance sites and see where the other site stands. Check to see that you can call not only the individual you are talking to, but any other contact information in whois and on the site itself and see if you feel you can trust them. Do your homework before saying Yes.

Comment: I've started sharing content now. Here's an example for anyone that's interested: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-classthis-in-java I think what you said about not sharing my unique content is smart. I get back links for generic articles, which may be a lever for my more impactful articles.